# Is it always possible to express an operator in terms of creation/annihilation operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, matrix-elements

I'm referring to *"Path integral approach to birth-death processes on a lattice"*, L. Peliti, J. Physique 46, 1469-1483 (1985), available at: [http://people.na.infn.it/~peliti/path.pdf](http://people.na.infn.it/%7Epeliti/path.pdf)

The article is about a reformulation of the master equation for a Markov process in terms of the path-integral formalism. However my question is mainly about Quantum Mechanics.

The author defines a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, an orthogonal basis of which is given by $\mid n \rangle$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with:

$$ \langle n \mid m \rangle = n! \delta_{n,m}. $$

The creation/annihilation operators are defined on $\mathcal{H}$ as follows:

$$ a \mid n \rangle = n \mid n - 1 \rangle, $$
$$ \pi \mid n \rangle = \mid n + 1 \rangle. $$

and they are easily to be seen each other's hermitean conjugates, according to the scalar product just defined.

The conventions are a little bit different from Quantum Mechanics, but this is not really relevant for my question. The author implies that it is possible to rewrite every operator $O: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ only in terms  (sums of products) of creation/annihilation operators.

I cannot demonstrate this assertion. I have tried taking the matrix elements of a generic operator $O$, and demonstrating that everything can be rewritten in terms of $a$ and $\pi$ but actually this is not working.

Comment: If you write the generic operator $O=\sum_{n,m} o_{n,m} a^{\dagger n} a^m$ and compute its matrix elements you'll get an infinite linear system. You need to prove that this system is solvable. Note that it has structure because any term with $n+m>i+j$ doesn't contribute to the $ij$ matrix element. So I would recommend an inductive strategy grouping the equations by $n+m=0,1,2,\ldots$. All you need to do is prove that there are enough new coefficients $o_{n,m}$ at each order to solve the new equations that arise at that order.

Comment: Starting from an expression : 
$O = \sum_{m,n=0}^{+\infty} A_{m,n} \Pi^m a^n$, we get : 
$O_{m' n'} = \langle m'|O|n' \rangle = \sum_{m-n=m'-n', n \leq n'} \frac{n'! m'!}{n!}A_{m,n}$. Finally, one has to express the $A_{m,n}$ in function of the $O_{m' n'} $. It is worth beginning with $n′=0$, increase $m′$ at fixed $n′$ ,then increase $n′$, and so on.

Comment: January 13th, 2024: _404 Link Not Found._

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Let us first review the setting to fix the notation. Let
   $$[a,a^{\dagger}]~=~1,\tag{1}$$
   and let $|0\rangle$ be the vacuum/ground state: $$a|0\rangle=0.\tag{2}$$
   Define
   $$|n\rangle~:=~ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}(a^{\dagger})^n|0\rangle.\tag{3}$$
   Then
   $$\begin{align} a |n\rangle ~=~& \sqrt{n} |n-1\rangle, \cr a^{\dagger} |n\rangle ~=~& \sqrt{n+1} |n+1\rangle,\cr \langle n |m\rangle ~=~& \delta_{n,m}. \end{align}\tag{4}$$
   Consider the corresponding [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space) ${\cal H}$
   with the completeness relation
   $$ {\bf 1}~=~\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}|n\rangle\langle n|.\tag{5}$$
2. Now let us address OP's question. An arbitrary linear operator is of the form
   $$\begin{align} T~=~& \sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{N}_0} |n\rangle T_{nm} \langle m|, \cr 
   T_{nm}~:=~&\langle n|T |m\rangle~\in~ \mathbb{C},\end{align}\tag{6}$$
   so it is enough to study operators of the form $|n\rangle  \langle m|$.
3. *Example:* The projection operator on the vacuum/ground state is
   $$ |0\rangle\langle 0|~=~:e^{-a^{\dagger}a}:~\equiv~\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(a^{\dagger})^n a^n,\tag{7}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/687291/2451) Phys.SE post.
4. We can now derive a bijective correspondence with creation/annihilation operators:
   $$\begin{align} 
   |n\rangle\langle m|~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~&
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} (a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle\langle 0| a^m\frac{1}{\sqrt{m!}}\cr
   ~\stackrel{(7)}{=}~&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n! m!}} (a^{\dagger})^n :e^{-a^{\dagger}a}: a^m\cr
   ~=~&\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!\sqrt{n! m!}} (a^{\dagger})^{n+k} a^{m+k},
   \end{align}\tag{8}$$
   and conversely,
   $$\begin{align} 
   (a^{\dagger})^n a^m~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~&
   (a^{\dagger})^n \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0}|k\rangle\langle k|a^m\cr
   ~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~&
   \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0} \frac{\sqrt{(n+k)!(m+k)!}}{k!}  |n+k\rangle\langle m+k|.
   \end{align}\tag{9}$$

Comment: I am concerned about the completeness of the basis. How can we be sure that all possible states of the theory can be expressed as a linear combination of the |n> states ? btw thank you for replying.

Comment: We can't. Completeness is an (implicit) assumption.