# Can $A_{nm} = |n\rangle \langle m|$ be written in terms of boson operators $b, b^\dagger$?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator, bosons

I am curious whether all operators can be written as a linear combination of product of boson operators $b, b^\dagger$.

More precisely, consider the single harmonic oscillator Hilbert space $H$, whose orthonormal basis is $\{|n\rangle\}_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$. We have ladder operators $b$ and $b^\dagger$ such that
$$b|0\rangle =0, \quad b^\dagger |n\rangle =\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle.$$
Then, can an operator $A_{nm} =  |n\rangle \langle m|$ be written by only using $b, b^\dagger$?

If this is true, then one may say that $b, b^\dagger$ are "complete" in the sense that they span the whole algebra of operators on $H$.

Comment: It could, around the vacuum projector: n creators on the left of it, and m annihilators on the right.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Then, can the vacuum projector be written in terms of $b,b^\dagger$?

Comment: [Yes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687291/relationship-between-normal-ordered-vacuum-state-and-parity-operator).

Comment: According to Louisell and  Fan, $|0\rangle\langle 0|=1−+(−1)/2!+...$, with zeros at n=1,2,3,... The elegant formulation is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/687438/66086).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for noting me the elegant formulation!

Comment: Actually, at integer eigenvalues, $\operatorname{sinc}(\pi N) \equiv \sin (\pi N)~/(\pi N)$ or any power of it shares the same property. You have more freedom than you think, and can finesse idempotence...