# Paradox when expressing an operator in terms of creation/annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics, coherent-states

I'm trying to expand an arbitrary operator using creation/annihilation operators following [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80845/289541), where $|m\rangle \langle n|$ is expressed as
$$
|n\rangle  \langle m|~=~\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0} c^{nm}_k (a^{\dagger})^{n+k} a^{m+k},
$$
and $c^{nm}_k$ is solution of
$$
\delta_k^0~=~\sum_{r=0}^k c^{nm}_{k-r} \sqrt{ \frac{(n+k)!}{r!} \frac{(m+k)!}{r!} }.
$$
But I met a paradox. Let
$$
\hat{O}=|m\rangle \langle n|=\sum{C^{mn}_{kl}\hat{a}^{\dagger k}\hat{a}^l},
$$
thus
$$
\langle \beta|m\rangle \langle n|\alpha \rangle =\sum{C^{mn}_{kl}
\langle \beta| \hat{a}^{\dagger k}\hat{a}^l}|\alpha\rangle 
$$
where $|\alpha\rangle,|\beta\rangle$ are coherent states. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{L}.\mathrm{H}.\mathrm{S}.&=\mathrm{e}^{-\left( |\alpha |^2+|\beta |^2 \right) /2}\frac{\beta ^{*m}\alpha ^n}{\sqrt{m!n!}}\\
 =\mathrm{R}.\mathrm{H}.\mathrm{S}.&=\sum{C^{mn}_{kl}\beta ^{*k}\alpha ^l}.
\end{aligned}
$$
From above equations it can be seen that RHS is an analytic function of $\beta^*$ and $\alpha$ while LHS is not because of the modulus in the exponential. Then we reach the conclusion that $|m\rangle \langle n|$ cannot be expanded by creation/annihilation operators, and the question in the mentioned post still remains: [Is it always possible to express an operator in terms of creation/annihilation operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80787/289541)

Comment: Your RHS expression is missing a $\langle\beta\mid\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it always possible to express an operator in terms of creation/annihilation operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80787/)